# Save a Trello board and restore to previous state in case of mistakes

Tags: trello

Is there a way to save a Trello board and allow an admin to restore to a checkpoint or a previous save state?

When a member makes a mistake and deletes something by accident, I want to be able to restore it.

Answer (score 5):

You can always export the complete board: `board menu > Share, Print and Export > Export to JSON` and export the board again after the person made a mistake.

Then do a diff with some program that supports that (Notepad++ or TortoiseDiff) and check for differences. You can undo it yourself.

I haven't found a way to import a board yet. Only exporting seems to be supported at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old card but I found an intelligent fix for the future just in case someone else runs into this problem in the future. i.e the mistake has already occured and you didn't export board, then do the following:

1. If you downloaded the trello app on mobile, immediately turn off all
   internet sources i.e wifi/3g etc.
2. Then visit the trello app on mobile.
3. Since internet was off before you opened app, trello
   wouldn't have updated the changes on mobile.
4. You can search through the cards and play around with whatever you need.